# Avoid duplication using Spring and Java Config beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

I am having in Class A the following beans:

```
@Bean
public AsyncItemProcessor OneUploadAsyncItemProcessor() {
    // ...
    asyncItemProcessor.setDelegate(processor(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION));
    // ...

    return asyncItemProcessor;
}

@Scope(value = "step", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
@Bean
public ItemProcessor<MyItem, MyItem> processor(@Value("#{jobParameters[pushMessage]}") String pushMessage, @Value("#{jobParameters[jobId]}") String jobId) {
    return new PushItemProcessor(pushMessage, jobId);
}
```

Now I have in a class B the following:

```
@Bean
public AsyncItemProcessor TwpUploadAsyncItemProcessor() {
    // ...
    asyncItemProcessor.setDelegate(processor(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION, OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION));

    return asyncItemProcessor;
}
```

How I can Inject into class B the bean processor (which defined on class A) without duplicate it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to "autowire" it in class `B`. Something like:

```
class B {
  @Autowire
  //@Qualifier(value = "OneUploadAsyncItemProcessor")
  [modifier] AsyncItemProcessor OneUploadAsyncItemProcessor;
}
```

I'm assuming you do not want –and hence going to delete- the bean `TwpUploadAsyncItemProcessor` from class `B` and include/autowire the (already defined) bean `OneUploadAsyncItemProcessor` from class `A`. If so, the `@Qualifier` annotation is not needed.

On the other hand if you want to autowire `OneUploadAsyncItemProcessor` without deleting `TwpUploadAsyncItemProcessor` and/or define (in the future) [another bean](http://spring.io/blog/2014/11/04/a-quality-qualifier) of type `AsyncItemProcessor` you are going to need the `@Qualifier` annotation.

Comment: i dont want to inject OneUploadAsyncItemProcessor i want to Inject procssor into class B. pay attention that processor has some properties

Comment: It's the same approach, just inject/autowire the bean `processor` into class `B`.

But keep in mind that, since the bean is created in class `A` and you are injecting it in class `B`, the value for the `#{jobParameters[pushMessage]}` expression will be computed at run-time within the `A` scope.